# Remove the comma at the last item. Using fwrite in php

Tags: php, mysql, fwrite

hi i'm trying to remove the comma at the last item of columns

```
$return .= "INSERT INTO `".$table."` (";
while($column = $resultCol->fetch_assoc()) {
    $return .= "`".$column['col']."`, ";
}
$return .= ") VALUES ()";
rtrim($return, ", ");
fwrite($handle, $return);
```

but it doesn't work. help please.

Comment: Switch `$return .= ") VALUES ()";` and `rtrim($return, ", ");`

Comment: `rtrim($return, ", ");
$return .= ") VALUES ()";
fwrite($handle, $return);`

i've tried your suggestion but it didn't work. result: (`col1`, `col2`, `col3`, `col4`, `col5`, ) VALUES ()

Comment: sorry, you have to set `$return = rtrim...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also try this -

```
$return .= "INSERT INTO `".$table."` (";
$cols= array();
while($column = $resultCol->fetch_assoc()) {
    $cols[]= "`".$column['col']."`";
}
$return .= implode(',', $cols) . ") VALUES ()";
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$return .= ") VALUES ()";
rtrim($return, ", ");
```

Replace with:

```
$return .= rtrim($return, ", ");
$return .= ") VALUES ()";
```

Answer (score 0):

Use rtrim function when while loop completed.
Try this:

```
$return .= "INSERT INTO `".$table."` (";
while($column = $resultCol->fetch_assoc()) {
    $return .= "`".$column['col']."`, ";
}

$return .= rtrim($return,',');
$return .= ") VALUES ()";
rtrim($return, ", ");
fwrite($handle, $return);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$return .= "INSERT INTO `".$table."` (";
while($column = $resultCol->fetch_assoc()) {
    $return .= "`".$column['col']."`, ";
}
$return = rtrim($return, ", ").") VALUES ()";
fwrite($handle, $return);
```